# How to Merge rows in Crystals Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I cant find a way to merge rows with the same value.

Current Crystal Report:
[image: Current Crystal Report]

Wanted to display like this:
[image: Wanted to display like this]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to selectively suppress (using the suppress expression) the repeating values so that:
In a 1-repeat case, they are not suppressed
In a 2-repeat case, only the 1st row is visible
In a 3-repeat case, only the 2nd row is visible
etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the report to a cross-tab, with those sections as groups, you could get close. You would need to move the model and quantity to the right though.